# Check continuity of a function in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

> Let $f$ be the function :
>   $$ f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> y\sin(1/x),  &x\not= 0 \\
> y, & x = 0
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Determine whether it is continuous at $(0,0)$ ?

I tried using epsilon-method by
$
\vert f(x,y)_{}-f(0,y)_{}\vert \leq \vert y \vert < \epsilon
$

But I think this is incorrect as we need to prove the above equation in neighbourhood of $x$, not $y$.

Answer (score 2):

I claim that for every $(x,y)$ with $\|(x,y)\| < \varepsilon$, $|f(x,y)| < \varepsilon$.

If $x=0$, then $f(x,y) = y$. We know that $\|(0,y)\| = |y| < \varepsilon$, so $|f(x,y)| < \varepsilon$.

Otherwise, $|f(x,y)| = |y \sin(1/x)| \le |y| < \varepsilon$.

Therefore, the function is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Instead of $\sin(1/x)x$ one can have any bounded function, so $\sin(1/x)$ may be a red herring.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe indeed, it is a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

For $x \ne 0$ we have:

$$0 \le \left|f(x,y)\right| = |y| \underbrace{\left|\sin\frac1x\right|}_{\le 1} \le |y| \le  \|(x, y)\|_2$$

For $x = 0$ we have:

$$\left|f(x,y)\right| = |y| \le \|(x,y)\|_2$$

So for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have: $$0 \le |f(x,y)|\le \|(x,y)\|_2 \xrightarrow{(x,y) \to (0,0)} 0$$

Therefore, by the squeeze theorem,$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = 0 = f(0,0)$$

so $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.